# Local key-value storage other than NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, icloud, key-value

I have followed the Apple documentation on syncing preferences via iCloud - essentially, iterating over every key in the 'updated' user info and setting it in `[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults].`

But I have some other data I would like to persist in the same format but which should not be synced - just a small array of `NSDictionaries`.

Is there a way to store these in the same fashion but in a separate place? Or should I change my 'update form iCloud' method to explicitly exclude these by key name? That seems a little inflexible and error prone to me (remembering to update the 'keys to exclude' whenever I change what I want to store locally).

Comment: are we just talking about writing nsdictionaries to local plist files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store such data in "<Library folder>/Application Support/<app bundle id>" - use the standard API to locate the user's Library folder (which will be in your container). The "Application Support" folder itself may not exist so you must check and create if needed. Your own app's folder won't exist unless you create it, so check and create.

The various collection's have methods to read/write from URL's, e.g. for `NSArray`:

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL;
- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)aURL atomically:(BOOL)flag;
```

Once you have the path to the directory above create a URL for an appropriately named file, e.g. "theArrayOfDictionaries.plist", and use these methods to read/write to it. The only caveat is the collection must only contain types that can be stored in a property list. If you have non-plist types, e.g. `NSColor` or your own classes, then you need to convert them to `NSData` before/after the write/read - see [this page for how to do this for `NSColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/StoringNSColorInDefaults.html), other types can be handled similarly.

HTH.

Comment: This is the approach that I normally use to save some basic user settings. For settings that I access frequently in the app, I will occasionally read the setting into memory to avoid the extra file read, but normally this works pretty well